# I0ERROR:[Errno 13] Permission denied for a .txt file

Tags: 12.04, permissions, python

I'm trying to install a program called [openSurfaces](https://github.com/seanbell/opensurfaces) on a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04.

When I run `bash ./install_all.sh` it (after running smoothly for a bit) returns the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2727, in <module>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 700, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2727, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2227, in activate
    self.insert_on(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2334, in insert_on
    self.check_version_conflict()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2373, in check_version_conflict
    for modname in self._get_metadata('top_level.txt'):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in _get_metadata
    for line in self.get_metadata_lines(name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1209, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1201, in get_metadata
    return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info,name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1316, in _get
    stream = open(path, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0.egg-info/top_level.txt'
```

Okay, so it seems like some `top_level.txt` is the cause of the problems. 
As such, i have tried to following:

```
chmod a+x /usr/.../top_level.txt
chmod o+r /usr/.../top_level.txt
```

and

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/...top_level.txt
```

Furthermore, I used `gsku nautilus` to manually go the folder to change the ownership from root, to no avail. And as last, running `su root` returns the error `Error: don't run this as root. The script will request your password later`

I've been looking further, but I can't find anything that seems to help.

Comment: Please check that link its broken.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the openSurfaces, it appears that it calls `scripts/install/install_all.sh` , which then calls `scripts/install/install_python.sh` , and that calls `pip` to install virtualenv. It's difficult to tell which particular command is failing, since the error thrown doesn't reference the script that ran it.  I would suggest you ask the devs a question on github , since it could potentially be a bug they might wanna fix.

Comment: Also, please don't do `chown -R` on anything in `/usr` level folder, like ever. It can lead to bad consequences.

Comment: @George. The links appears to work fine for me on multiple devices. [Nonetheless, as a back-up, the orginal link refers to the 'Code(Github repository)' on this site.](http://opensurfaces.cs.cornell.edu/)

Comment: @Serg Thank you. I will. I'm regretfully not well versed in Ubuntu, thank you for the advice on `chown -R`.